# Unit test case for dynamodb pagination or scan operation for more than 1MB data using Python Unittest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need to code test case coverage for dynamodb scan operation.

```
def get_employer_list():
employer_list = "{}"
try:
    response = TABLE.scan()
    employer_list = response['Items']
    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response =
```

TABLE.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
employer_list.extend(response['Items'])
return employer_list
except Exception as ex:
LOGGER.error(str(ex))
return employer_list

Please help me to cover below lines of code from above code :

```
response = TABLE.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    employer_list.extend(response['Items'])
```

I am mocking dynamo db table but not able to mock the logic in while loop. Also, not sure how to cover those 2 lines from the code

````
```python
import json
import unittest
import boto3
import main
from moto import mock_dynamodb
import dateutil.tz
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch

eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz("US/Eastern")

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock_dynamodb
def create_mock_table(self):
    boto3.setup_default_session()
    self.table_name = "EMPLOYER_TABLE"
    dynamodb_mock = boto3.resource(
        "dynamodb",
        region_name="us-east-1",
        aws_access_key_id="ak",
        aws_secret_access_key="sk",
    )
    table = dynamodb_mock.create_table(
        TableName=self.table_name,
        KeySchema=[{"AttributeName": "companyId", "KeyType": 
 "HASH"}],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {"AttributeName": "companyId", "AttributeType": "S"},
            {"AttributeName": "companyName", "AttributeType": "S"},
            {"AttributeName": "trgtAdopted", "AttributeType": "S"},
        ],
        BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST",
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
            {
                "IndexName": "trgtAdopted-companyName-index",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {"AttributeName": "trgtAdopted", "KeyType": 
    "HASH"},
                    {"AttributeName": "companyName", "KeyType": 
  "RANGE"},
                ],
                "Projection": {"ProjectionType": "ALL"},
            }
        ],
    )
    table.meta.client.get_waiter("table_exists").wait(TableName=self.table_name)
    assert table.table_status == "ACTIVE"
    item_list = [
        {
            "companyId": "TEST1234",
            "companyName": "TestCompany1",
            "trgtAdopted": "True"
        },
        {
            "companyId": "TEST2345",
            "companyName": "TestCompany2",
            "trgtAdopted": "True"
        },
        {
            "companyId": "TEST3456",
            "companyName": "TestCompany3",
            "trgtAdopted": "True"
        },
        {
            "companyId": "TEST4567",
            "companyName": "TestCompany4",
            "trgtAdopted": "True"
        }
    ]
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for item in item_list:
            batch.put_item(
                Item=item
            )

    return table

@mock_dynamodb
def test_handler(self):
    event = {
        "resource": "/app/api/v1/employer-info",
        "path": "/app/api/v1/employer-info",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "headers": {},
        "apiId": "xrm2v4rsve",
        "body": "",
        "isBase64Encoded": "false",
    }
    main.TABLE = self.create_mock_table()
    mock_scan_response = main.TABLE.scan()
    mock_employer_list = mock_scan_response['Items']
    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in mock_scan_response:
        response = main.TABLE.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=mock_scan_response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        mock_employer_list.extend(response['Items'])
    mock_handler_response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({"employer-list": mock_employer_list}),
    }
    result = main.handler(event, MagicMock())
    self.assertEqual(
        result,
        mock_handler_response
    )

@mock_dynamodb
def test_get_employer_list_with_exception(self):
    self.assertEqual(
        main.get_employer_list(),
        "{}"
    )

@patch('boto3.resource')
def test_get_employer_list_with_no_data(self, mock_dynamo):
    mock_table = Mock()
    mock_table.scan.return_value = []
    mock_dynamo.return_value.Table.return_value = mock_table
    result = main.get_employer_list()
    expected_result = '{}'
    self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to stack! When writing unittests, it is important to know what you are trying to test instead of just having code coverage. That being said, you will need to patch TABLE.scan, to return a predefined value or if it is an integration test, you should create a mock version of your TABLE, and pointing your code at that table instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the test code too?

Comment: I have added unit test case code. I am trying to mock the dynamodb table and able to test basic functionality. but not to test code inside the function specifically while loop.